# crash when attempt to use onClick in xml to access a method within a function in a different class. How do I solve this?

Tags: android

Note: I realize that there are no onClick in the xml because every tim i try to link it to AlexRevolver.shoot() or .reload() the program crashes.

Any ideas on how to fix this, also the TextView's are not getting updated

**Display.Java**

```
package com.example.firedatgun_v2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Display extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void main(){
        gun AlexRevolver = new gun(0);//create a new gun Object
        Button reload_V = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reload_B);
        Button fire_V = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fire_B);
        TextView bulletCount_V = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletCount_TV);
        TextView infoDisplay_V = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_TV);
        infoDisplay_V.setText("Magazine Size: " + AlexRevolver.magSize);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**gun.Java**

```
package com.example.firedatgun_v2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class gun extends Activity{


    public  TextView bulletCount_Var = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletCount_TV);
    public  TextView infoDisplay_Var = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_TV);    
    public int magSize = 6; //create the variable called "magSize"                          //set the size of the Magazine to 6
    public int bulletCount; //create a variable called "bulletCount"

    public gun(int startingBullets) {
        bulletCount = startingBullets;
    }

    public void reload(){
        bulletCount = magSize;
    }

    public void shoot(){
        if (bulletCount < 0){
            infoDisplay_Var.setText("Bang!");
            bulletCount --;
            bulletCount_Var.setText(bulletCount);
        }
        else{
            infoDisplay_Var.setText("Reload now");
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_display.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Display" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/bullets_in_mag"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bulletCount_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
        android:text="@string/clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fire_B"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/info_TV"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/info_TV"
        android:text="@string/Fire" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reload_B"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fire_B"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fire_B"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/info_TV"
        android:text="@string/reload" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

if you need more data, just post , any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of error do you get when it crashes?  Post a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Only when a *activity A* calls **setContentView** with a *layout a*, then that *activity A* can directly access the elements in the *layout a* using the **findViewById()** - means layout elements can be used directly by that *activity A* - or in other words*layout a* elements will not be directly accessible to *activity  B* through **findViewById()**.
2. Also Which means that for the events directly set in *layout a*, when fired will always look for a matching function in the *activity A* in which that layout was inflated through **setContentView**.

In your case ***Activity gun*** is not the activity that inflated the ***layout activity_display*** instead ***Activity Display*** inflated that layout. so for any events directly specified in ***layout activity_display***,when triggered will look for matching function in the ***Activity Display*** - if a match is absent error will be raised

Modified Code

Display.java

```
 ....
 ...

  public class Display extends Activity {
   gun AlexRevolver;
     @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    AlexRevolver = new gun(0) 
     AlexRevolver.reload_V = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reload_B);
    AlexRevolver.fire_V = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fire_B);

    AlexRevolver.bulletCount_V = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletCount_TV);
    AlexRevolver.infoDisplay_V = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_TV);
    AlexRevolver.infoDisplay_V.setText("Magazine Size: " + AlexRevolver.magSize);
     AlexRevolver.reload_V.setOnClickListener(AlexRevolver);
     AlexRevolver.fire_V.setOnClickListener(AlexRevolver);

  }
```

gun.java

gun can be an simple class instead of extending Activity

```
.....
.....
public class gun implements OnClickListener {


public  TextView bulletCount_V;
public  TextView infoDisplay_V;
public  Button fire_V;
public  Button reload_V;


public gun(int startingBullets) {
    bulletCount = startingBullets;
}
.....
.....
...
public void onClick(View v)
{
   switch(v.getId())
   {
     case R.id.reload_B:
      this.reload();
     break;
     case R.id.fire_B:
     this.shoot();
     break;
   }
 }
}
```

Note: The above code does not follow proper **oop**, *Java Interfaces* can be used to achieve the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
public class gun extends Activity{
    public  TextView bulletCount_Var = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletCount_TV);
```

You will get `NullPointerException`. `findViewById` looks fora view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout.

Also in `Display` Activity you do not call `main()`.

Change your activity code to

```
public class Display extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView bulletCount_Var,infoDisplay_var; 
    Buttom reload_V,fire_V;
    public int bulletCount=0; // initially count is 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        reload_V = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reload_B);
        fire_V = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fire_B);
        bulletCount_Var = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bulletCount_TV);
        infoDisplay_Var = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_TV);
        infoDisplay_V.setText("Magazine Size: " + AlexRevolver.magSize);
        realod_V.setOnClickListener(this);  
        fire_V.setOnClickListener(this);        
    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      switch(v.getId())
      {
           case R.id.reload_B :
              // do reload calculation
              // update bulletCount_Var
           break; 
           case R.id.fire_B :
             // do fire calculation
             // update infoDisplay_Var 
           break; 
      } 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Write button listeners. Do calculation and update text view in activtiy. I do not knwo why you use `gun` class which extends Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have two activities in your posted code as both extends Activity: gun and Display. And you can't instantiate the activity like any other java object. There are certain protocols you have to follow for communication between activities. But from you posted code you don't need multiple activities.

Moreover, each activity on creation, instantiate the layout and that instance of the layout (and subelements as well) belongs to instance of that activity.

Android has good documentation on [layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)